# Google Keep, lost notes during upgrade because notes not saved in the cloud, Android backup in Google Drive available?

Tags: google-keep

I would like to know what happened to the option to keep Google Keep notes to Google Drive. I can remember seeing this option on a version of Google Keep on my previous phone that was reset (Android 6), but can't see the option on my new phone (Android 7).

I would like to know what happened to the option, and, since I lost my notes since the app was not working properly, I would like to see where I can find the backup in Google Drive. Anyone know where I can find it?

Comment: I'm not aware of this.  But I do know that Keep syncs to the cloud so that you can log in from anywhere and find your notes in Keep.  With that in mind, you should be able to install the app and log in and have it sync up.

Comment: Yes, I upgraded my phone and installed keep in it, but all the notes written with my previous phone were gone. Not the ones written in keep on the phone previous to that though. However, on my previous phone I was noticing that my notes were not syncing because logging into keep.google.com waa not showing any of the new notes and tapping sync in settings wasn't doing the trick.

Comment: I don't think Keep saves anything locally. So, it would be difficult to get back all those notes.

Comment: @WrichikBasu - I disagree. I believe local copies DO exist. My tablet is Wifi-only, and I can still read my Keep items in the car. In fact I use it this way for trip-related lists during travel. It will synch any changes once a connection can be re-established. I have not tried a disconnected NEW item, but changes and edits are fine once synched.